# Editing res.cls to increase the left column width

Tags: resume, cv, class-options

I'm a beginner to Tex. I was using an Overleaf template to create a CV. [Link: https://www.overleaf.com/project/5cdbf1b52aab4345446ebf8c ]. I want to know how I can increase the left column width so that I can add new section named ACHIEVEMENTS. Currently, the left column is full I think. Because I'm getting the warning `Overfull \hbox (1.75659pt too wide) in paragraph at lines`. Is it possible that I can get a permanent solution by editing the `res.cls` file? If so, can anyone show the part of the code I need to edit?

I've also attached a screenshot. I want some spacing between the section and points like in the normal overleaf template.

[image: Screenshot of the pdf generated]

Comment: `res.cls` should be buried, or put in a bin. But the internet keeps it alive. You honestly should have a look at alternatives.

Comment: Use something based on say `moderncv` instead

Comment: I understand that `res.cls` is old. But I'm preparing an academic orientated CV and this template looked good. @Johannes_B

Comment: Can you suggest some alternative packages @daleif

Comment: I already did....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments on the question notwithstanding, there's no need to edit the `.cls` file. The class has a command built to adjust the width of the left column: `\newsectionwidth`. You can use it to set a custom left column width like this:

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}  
\newsectionwidth{1.5in}

\begin{document}

\begin{resume}

\section{ACHIEVEMENTS}
\textbf{Award Winner}, Any Organization, Any City\\

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. @Paul Gessler